# copy and unzip files to remote machine - ant

Tags: ant, ssh, exec, scp

I need to copy the zip files from local machine and paste in remote machine and unzip those files in remote machine.

I know the first part can be done using the scp (copy zip files from local and paste in remote machine) but how to do the second part using ant?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [sshexec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) to call the command line `unzip` command on the remote machine (assuming the remote machine has unzip installed).

```
<!-- local directory containing the files to copy -->
<property name="archives" location="C:\path\to\zipfiles" />
<property name="archives.destination" value="/home/testuser/archives" />
<property name="unzip.destination" value="/home/testuser/unpacked" />

<fileset id="zipfiles.to.copy" dir="${archives}" includes="*.zip" />

<!-- copy the archives to the remote server -->
<scp todir="${user}:${password}@host.example.com:${archives.destination}">
  <fileset refid="zipfiles.to.copy" />
</scp>

<!-- Build the command line for unzip - the idea here is to turn the local
     paths into the corresponding paths on the remote, i.e. to turn
     C:\path\to\zipfiles\file1.zip;C:\path\to\zipfiles\file2.zip... into
     /home/testuser/archives/file1.zip /home/testuser/archives/file2.zip

     For this to work there must be no spaces in any of the zipfile names.
-->
<pathconvert dirsep="/" pathsep=" " property="unzip.files" refid="zipfiles.to.copy">
  <map from="${archives}" to="${archives.destination}" />
</pathconvert>

<!-- execute the command.  Use the "-d" option to unzip so it will work
     whatever the "current" directory on the remote side -->
<sshexec host="host.example.com" username="${user}" password="${password}"
  command="/bin/sh -c '
    for zipfile in ${unzip.files}; do
      /usr/bin/unzip -d ${unzip.destination} $$zipfile ; done '" />
```

The `unzip` command can take a number of other options, see its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) for full details. For example the `-j` option will ignore any directory hierarchy inside the zip files and put all the extracted files directly in the target directory. And `-o` will force overwrite existing files in the target directory without prompting.

Comment: can you please give me example where i need to unzip all the files in one particular dir and put those unzipped file in someother dir using sshexec?

Comment: awesome great. its working fine. two questions. 1. how to make this program to unzip all the files in one folder and move extracted files into one directory.? 2. if the files are already unzipped in destination dir and if i try to unzip again it asks for replace the files? how to always set yes for replacing the files? thanks in advance.

Comment: @coolgokul I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 1 but I've added some details that might help.

Comment: Awesome.. working good.. My 1st question was, say i have folder named "sources" in which has many zip files. (file1.zip, abc.zip, 123.zip and special character named folders etc)... now i need to unzip all the files inside the sources folder and put all the unzipped files into "Temp" folder. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: I think that's what my code above will do - your "sources" directory is the `archives` property (the directory containing the original zip files on the local side) and your "Temp" folder is `unzip.destination` (the folder on the server where the contents unzipped from those files will end up).  If you want all the unzipped files to end up directly in "Temp" rather than in subdirectories then you just need to add `-j`, i.e. `unzip -j -d ${unzip.destination} ....`